# Is it possible to use multiple Adaptive Dialogs generated by Bot Framework Composer in a single bot?

Tags: botframework

Use case:  I have a LUIS Dispatch Model in front 2 Composer-built LUIS models - each of which front up a Composer-built Adaptive Dialog conversation.  e.g.

- LUIS model 1 - home automation
- LUIS model 2 - weather

Once the LUIS intent is recognised I want to transition into either one of these three processes.

My strategy for integrating the Composer Generated Adaptive Dialogs into the Bot is based on the example here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/adaptive-dialog/declarative

And I add the two proesses to the `ResourceExplorer` in my adapter and then in my Bot, I am loading the dialogs and creating a parent `AdaptiveDialog` and wrap it in a `DialogManager` before delegating to that on `OnTurnAsync`. :

(note: I've stripped back and simplified a lot of this code to help me debug through the issue)

```
var adaptiveDialogs = new DialogSet();

foreach (var resource in _resourceExplorer.GetResources(".dialog").Where(r => _composedDialogNames.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(r.Id))))
{
    var subDialog = DeclarativeTypeLoader.Load<AdaptiveDialog>(resource, _resourceExplorer, DebugSupport.SourceMap);
    adaptiveDialogs.Add(subDialog);
}

// Note - at this point adaptiveDialogs correctly contains two Composer created dialogs 

var dialog = new AdaptiveDialog()
{
    AutoEndDialog = false,
    Dialogs = adaptiveDialogs,
    Triggers = new List<OnCondition>() {
        new OnBeginDialog() {
            Actions = new List<Dialog>()
            {
                new CodeAction(async (context, o) =>
                {
                    await context.Context.SendActivityAsync("say something to me");
                    return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting, o); 
                }),                            
                new BeginDialog(adaptiveDialogs.GetDialogs().ElementAt(0).Id),
                new BeginDialog(adaptiveDialogs.GetDialogs().ElementAt(1).Id),
                new RepeatDialog()
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The issue I am having is that when this runs, the line `new BeginDialog(adaptiveDialogs.GetDialogs().ElementAt(0).Id)` does not do anything if there is a subsequent Adaptive dialog loaded. (`new BeginDialog(adaptiveDialogs.GetDialogs().ElementAt(1).Id)` runs fine, by the way)

Any help would be hugely appreciated.